# Equivalent of while(1) in OCaml?

Tags: loops, while-loop, ocaml, read-eval-print-loop

I need to write a recursive function that keeps prompting the user for input. What is the correct way to implement the equivalent of while(1) in OCaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `break` and no `return` in OCaml. So I would respectfully suggest you don't really want to write `while true do ... done`.

If (as I suspect) there is a condition that should terminate the loop, you can write:

```
while not <condition> do
    . . .
done
```

It will often give you more idiomatic code if you write a recursive function along the following lines:

```
let rec loop a b c =
    if condition a b c then
        ()
    else
        let (a', b', c') = do_something a b c in
        loop a' b' c'
```

Comment: I would break out of the loop with exit 0. I don't need break or return. This is meant to be a command prompt style interface that takes simple inputs and responds with text based outputs.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield A third option, that stands between the endless loop and exit 0, is to bring up exceptions.

Comment: I thought of that, but I decided to keep it simple :-) But, good point.